# get timestamp of most recent comment of an article

Tags: 8, comments

I need the date of the last created/updated comment of an article. Are there any API functions in drupal 8 like node->most_recent_comment ? Or do I have to check every comments date of a node in a loop?

EDIT - Solution:

```
$node->comment->last_comment_timestamp;
```

Note that you'll have to change ->comment to the actual field name of the comments on your node.

Comment: check the comment_entity_statistics table. maybe there is a function as well but i havent checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @IvanJaros pointed out the comments statistics are stored in a database table. You don't need an API function to get them. The comment module does this for you and places them in the field while loading the node from storage:

```
function comment_entity_storage_load($entities, $entity_type) {
  ...
  // Load comment information from the database and update the entity's
  // comment statistics properties, which are defined on each CommentItem field.
  $result = \Drupal::service('comment.statistics')->read($entities, $entity_type);
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    // Skip fields that entity does not have.
    if (!$entities[$record->entity_id]->hasField($record->field_name)) {
      continue;
    }
    $comment_statistics = $entities[$record->entity_id]->get($record->field_name);
    $comment_statistics->cid = $record->cid;
    $comment_statistics->last_comment_timestamp = $record->last_comment_timestamp;
    $comment_statistics->last_comment_name = $record->last_comment_name;
    $comment_statistics->last_comment_uid = $record->last_comment_uid;
    $comment_statistics->comment_count = $record->comment_count;
  }
}
```

So you can access the statistics directly from the node field:

```
$node->comment->last_comment_timestamp;
$node->comment->last_comment_name;
$node->comment->last_comment_uid;
$node->comment->comment_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
$node->get('field_comments')->__get('created')->value;
```

Note that you'll have to change `field_comments` to the actual field name of the comments on your node.

Comment: You are right this shows the timestamp of the most recent comment: $last_date = $node->get('field_comments')->__get('last_comment_timestamp');

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer then.